# java.lang.IllegalStateException in code

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, handler

this is my code  inside postexecute of  async task it is giving illegalstate exception i tried every solution but not getting anything help me out

```
new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Fragment fragment = newFragmentNoOffer();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager =getActivity().getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        if (getActivity() != null) {
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        } else {
            fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
        }
    }
});
```

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
>        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss 
>       (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1411)
>         at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction 
>       (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1429)
>         at android.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal 
>       (BackStackRecord.java:687)
>        at android.app.BackStackRecord.commit (BackStackRecord.java:663)
>        at com.waypedia.activity.FragmentAppList$3$1.run 
>        (FragmentAppList.java)
>        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:739)
>         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
>         at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:224)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5526)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run 
>         (ZygoteInit.java:726)
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:616)

this is showing error in the devices above honeycomb

Comment: Did you try    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        //No call for super()
    }

?

Comment: I don't know anything about android programming (just java), but if I had to guess, `checkStateLoss` is throwing `IllegalStateException` because the `commit` cannot be performed *without* state loss.  Does `commitAllowingStateLoss` work?

Comment: no I did not used onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) in my fragment class